# Using pivot_wider to get true or false

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I'm trying to use pivot_wider to get a binary result for each country in each year between 1991 - 1995 like this table:

```
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| year | USA   | Israel | Sweden |
| 1991 | FALSE | TRUE   | TRUE   |
| 1992 | FALSE | FALSE  | TRUE   |
| 1993 | FALSE | TRUE   | TRUE   |
| 1994 | FALSE | FALSE  | TRUE   |
| 1995 | TRUE  | TRUE   | TRUE   |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
```

Of course, any binary indication will be great, besides true/false.

However, my data frame looks like:

```
 country =  c("Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Israel", "Israel",
                   "Israel", "USA")  
    year = c(1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1991,1993,1995,1995)
      df = as.data.frame(cbind(year,country))
    df


+---------+------+
| country | Year |
| Sweden  | 1991 |
| Sweden  | 1992 |
| Sweden  | 1993 |
| Sweden  | 1994 |
| Sweden  | 1995 |
| Israel  | 1991 |
| Israel  | 1993 |
| Israel  | 1995 |
| USA     | 1995 |
+---------+------+
```

I tried the following code and obtained the result below which is not what I'm looking for

```
  library(dplyr)
    df2 =  df %>%
      group_by(country) %>%
      mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = country, values_from = year) %>%
      select(-row)
    df2

+------+--------+--------+
| USA  | Israel | Sweden |
| 1995 | 1991   | 1991   |
| NA   | 1993   | 1992   |
| NA   | 1995   | 1993   |
| NA   | NA     | 1994   |
| NA   | NA     | 1995   |
+------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% mutate(val=1) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = country,values_from = val) %>% 
  mutate(across(-year, ~replace_na(.x, 0))) %>%
  mutate(across(-year, ~ifelse(.x==1, TRUE,FALSE)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  year  Sweden Israel USA  
  <fct> <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>
1 1991  TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
2 1992  TRUE   FALSE  FALSE
3 1993  TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
4 1994  TRUE   FALSE  FALSE
5 1995  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
```

Comment: A better way to do this with dplyr is just to add a "TRUE" column before pivoting and to use values_fill: 
df %>% 
  mutate("TRUE" = TRUE) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = country, values_from = "TRUE", values_fill = FALSE)

Answer (score 2):

here is a `data.table` solution

```
library( data.table )
#custom function, odetermins is the length of a vector >1 (TRUE/FALSE)
cust_fun <- function(x) length(x) > 0
#cast to wide, aggregating with the custom function above
dcast( setDT(df), year ~ country, fun.aggregate = cust_fun )

#    year Israel Sweden   USA
# 1: 1991   TRUE   TRUE FALSE
# 2: 1992  FALSE   TRUE FALSE
# 3: 1993   TRUE   TRUE FALSE
# 4: 1994  FALSE   TRUE FALSE
# 5: 1995   TRUE   TRUE  TRUE
```